# How can a 10th level Wizard travel to other planes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard, planes

I already know that there's the *[Plane Shift](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/planeShift.htm)* spell, but it needs a 7th-level slot that I don't have at 10th level. Are there any other ways — spells, magic items, or something else — that I could use at 10th level to travel to other planes, or a way I could gain access to a 7th level spell slot to cast *Plane Shift* with?

Comment: A little late, but welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. This question's 2 votes from closure, but more information may keep it open. Level and class were a good start, but it'd be useful to add a longer list of the resources that can be devoted to the project (e.g. time, money, manpower, magic, allies, feats). Also, including the *reason* for wanting to travel across planes would be helpful (that is, folks might be able to solve the actual problem *without* the wizard needing to hop planes). The more information provided, the better the answer. Thank you and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

### In Faerûn, yes you *can*!

On p153 of *City of Splendors: Waterdeep* is the 5th level spell *Halaster's fetch II*, which is a conjuration (calling) spell whose description says:

> As [*summon monster II*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#summon-monster-ii), except called creatures do not disappear at the end of the spell's duration. However, they become free-willed and outside the control of the caller after the spell expires.

On p130-2 of the *Planar Handbook* is the ur'epona which can [*plane shift*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#plane-shift) 1/day as a 9th level caster. According to *PlH* p134, the ur'epona can replace the celestial riding dog on the *summon monster II* list.

So you can get there with a 5th level spell. That is, *if* you have access to the *PlH*, and your DM is willing to allow you to summon an ur'epona, as the *PlH* suggests.